# Пробел после точки или запятой в регуляярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-forms

Есть гугл форма с проверкой текста в ответе с помощью регулярно выражения. Сейчас оно проверяет, чтобы в ответе использовался только английский язык и цифры, пробелы, двоеточия, тире, двойные кавычки, точки, запятые, восклицательный и вопросительные знаки и скобки. Кроме этого заставляет начинать ответ с заглавной буквы или цифры, а заканчивать точкой или знаками '!?'. А как сделать так, чтобы точка или запятая в тексте использовались только с пробелом после них?

```
^[A-Z0-9][0-9a-zA-Z\s:\-".,!?()]*[\.!?]$
```

Comment: Наверное, так - `^[A-Z0-9]([0-9a-zA-Z\s:"!?()-]|[.,]\s)*[.!?]$`.

Comment: Благодарю, работает. Каким простым оно теперь кажется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
^[A-Z0-9]([0-9a-zA-Z\s:"!?()-]|[.,]\s)*[.!?]$
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[A-Z0-9]` - буква или цифра из набора символов ASCII
- `(` - начало захватывающей подмаски:

  - `[0-9a-zA-Z\s:"!?()-]` - буква или цифра из набора символов ASCII, пробельный символ или один из символов `:"!?()-`
  - `|` - или
  - `[.,]\s` - точка или запятая, после которых следует один пробельный символ
- `)*` - конец подмаски, ноль или более повторов
- `[.!?]` - `.`, `!` или `?`
- `$` - конец строки.